# VS Code plugin to capture changes

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am writing a Visual Studio Code extension for internal use.

The idea is the capture changes on each save of the file and changes made (diff) will be pushed to our server through an API for analysis.

I am trying to find out which VS Code API which can help to capture the diff. Can someone put some light here?